# Angular js: Adding list of nested array properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, frontend

**Please help: hitting my head all the way,I am a new-bee to angular js, building a Quiz Application using angular js,

I have an issue adding array of nested properties to my controller**

[jsfiddle link showing the issue:](http://jsfiddle.net/raghav_puthu/Nu7rZ/121/)

**STEP BY STEP SCENARIO**

- I want to add a **question**
- each question has **4 options**, out of which 1 is selected as **right**
- I am able to get the UI but binding is not working for **Options**

**html is as below:**

```
<div ng-app>
<div class="new-question-container" ng-controller="newQuestionController">
    <h3>Add New Question</h3>
    <form class="new-question-form" novalidate name="newQuestionForm" data-ng-submit="save()">
        <div>
            <label for="QuestionDescription">Quesiton Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="QuestionDescription" data-ng-model="newQuestion.QuestionDescription" required />
        </div>

        Options<br/>
        <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
            <label for="options[i].OptionDescription">Option {{i}}</label>
            <input name="options[i].OptionDescription" type="text" data-ng-model="options[i].OptionDescription" required />
            Is right answer:
            <input type="radio" data-ng-model="options[i].IsAnswer" name="newQuestion" ng-value="true" />Yes
            <input type="radio" data-ng-model="options[i].IsAnswer" name="newQuestion" ng-value="false" />No
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Question" data-ng-disabled="newQuestionForm.$invalid" />
        <a href="#/" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>

    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**angular script as below**

```
    function newQuestionController($http, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.newQuestion = {};
    $scope.options = [{}];

    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.newQuestion.Options.push(options);
        alert($scope.newQuestion.QuestionDescription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize you `$scope` correct like this:

```
$scope.options = [{},{},{},{}];
```

and change the `ng-repeat` array to start from 0:

```
ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3]"
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu7rZ/123/) you can find a working example